# AWS Ground Truth text classification manifest using "source-ref" not displaying text

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

### Background

I'm trying out SageMaker Ground Truth, [an AWS service to help you label your data before using it in your ML algorithms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms.html).

The labeling job requires a manifest file which contains a JSON object per row that contains a `source` or a `source-ref`, see also the [Input Data section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-data-input.html) of the documentation.

### Setup

Source-ref is a reference to where the document is located in an S3 bucket like so

```
my-bucket/data/manifest.json
my-bucket/data/123.txt
my-bucket/data/124.txt

...
```

The manifest file looks like this (based on the [blog example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-sagemaker-ground-truth-build-highly-accurate-datasets-and-reduce-labeling-costs-by-up-to-70/)) :

```
{"source-ref": "s3://my-bucket/data/123.txt"}
{"source-ref": "s3://my-bucket/data/124.txt"}
...
```

### The problem

When I create the job, all I get is the `source-ref` value: **s3://my-bucket/data/123.txt** as the text, the contents of the file are not displayed.

I have tried creating jobs using a manifest that does not contain the s3 protocol, but I get the same result.

Is this a bug on their end or I'm I missing something?

### Observations

- I have tried to make all files public, thinking there may maybe permissions issue? but no
- I ensured that the content type of the file was text (s3 -> object -> properties -> metadata)
- If I use "source" and inline the text, it works properly, but I should be able to use individual documents as there is a limit on the file size specially if I have to label many or large documents!

Answer (score 4):

I am a member of AWS SageMaker Ground Truth team. Sorry to hear that you have difficulties in using certain features of our product.

From your post I presume you have multiple text files and each text files contains multiple lines. For text classification, in order to show preview in console, we currently support only the inline mode using "source" containing each line.

We understand it is not convenient to create such a manifest with embedded text as it is not trivial and time consuming. That is why we have provided a crawling feature in console (please see "create input manifest" link over the input manifest box) that takes an input s3Prefix and crawls all text files (with extensions .txt, .csv) in that prefix and read each line of each of the text files in the prefix, and creates a manifest with each line as {“source”:””}. Please let us know if you can crawl to create your manifest.

Please note that, currently crawler will only work if you have created s3://my-bucket/data/ folder from console and then uploaded all the text files in this folder (instead of using s3 cli sync tool to upload a local data/ directory).

Sorry if our documents are not clear and we are definitely taking your feedback to improve our product. For any question, please reach us here: https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/

Comment: If I understand correctly, If I want to use multiple Files, I have to do 2 things: 1) 1 line per document. 2) use the crawler to generate the manifest file. Is this correct?

Comment: #1 is not necessary if u use crawler. You can have multiple lines in each of the txt files (one line is line dataset object). Crawler can read line by line of each txt files.

Comment: Does the inline limitation still apply? The doc indicates otherwise https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-data-input.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your preprocessing lambda. The preprocessing lambda receives the objects from the manifest (in batches afaik), ie the s3 sources. The preprocessing lambda must read the files and return the actual content. It sounds like your preprocessing is passing the files location instead of content. Refer to the documentation. any example preprocessing lambda for text should be easily adjustable to your case